# using bluetooth headset over steam

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, steam

I've been playing L4D recently and people usually get irritated when you play without a proper headset.   Instead of running out and buying one, can i use my existing BT headset (jawbone), pair it to my PC, and use it on Steam?  How would I go about setting that up?

Just an FYI, i had paired it and while it shows up in Windows, it does not show up in Steam.

Comment: Does your pc have a bluetooth connection, if so which one?

Comment: Steam should be unrelated, it can use any microphone. I'd remove it from your tag/title.

Comment: Yes, except that when I tried this, the headset does not show up in Steam

Comment: Precise your question : do you want to have the headphone in Steam (to communicate with Steam friends in the given communicator), or do you want to have it in game (to be able to talk to people from a game ?

Because your question sounds like Steam related, but at same time you talk about people irritated during game.

Comment: any progress on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as pairing up your headset with you PC, you could also try and **force** it as the default audio output in windows. This helped when i was using my bluetooth stereo headset with Spotify.

> [image]
>
> (I couldn't find my bluetooth headset,
>   so i couldn't show it with a bluetooth
>   device)
>
> **Control Panel > Sound > Audio > Default Device > Choose Bluetooth
>   Headset**

Comment: Problem is that he probably wants to separate main sound (going to speakers) from voice talk (going to headphone, moreover it looks like a single ear one), so this method would make him have all sound in the small headphone.

I guess he would rather set the main input device (sound recording)

Comment: If this is the case, then keep the default playback device, and change the Sound recording device to bluetooth.

Comment: Just to add to pavsaund's answer, Windows 7 allows you to specify different devices for "Default device" and "Default communication device" - http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-default-playback-recording-audio-device

Comment: it would be helpful if you updated your answer to reference the recording device instead of (or in addition to) the playback device. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply attempt to pair with your bluetooth headset as you would have done from your phone. If your PC has a bluetooth adapter you should see a bluetooth icon in your system tray ([like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth)). Click it and try to pair with your headset.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could pair your bt headset but music quality will be awful. It's ok for conversation but not really suitable even for game sounds.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to use only the microphone from it, to communicate with people from game

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: As of May setting the Bluetooth device as your "Default Communication Device" in Windows will force Steam to use that for VoIP and use your speakers for game sounds.

Currently Steam games do not support separating the game audio and voice chat to separate devices.  There are numerous requests for this, so hopefully Valve will add it in the near future.

I tried this [tutorial on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzNk8FiNKy8&feature=related), but it hasn't worked yet.